# Null empty check for Custom Object in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I am having below null check
Amount is having below fields

```
Amount{
  Money amountToBePaid;
  Float percentage;
}
```

and Money is having below fields:

```
Money {

  String unit;
  BigDecimal value
}


private boolean checkIfAmountDefined(Amount amount){
  amountFlag=false;
  If (null != amount || !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(amount)) {
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(amount.getAmountToBePaid())&& 
       !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(amount.getPercentage())) {
      if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(amount.getAmountToBePaid().getValue()) || 
        !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(amount.getAmountToBePaid().getUnit())) {
        amountFlag = true;
        return amountFlag;
      }
    }
}
return amountFlag;
}
```

I need to check if the amount is not defined for which I am running below c    check .The issue is I am getting null pointer exception for somtimes with percentage ,sometimes with other field. I can not ignore any of the inner fields as based upon these field I will consider the Amount is defined or not. Any suggestion ?

Comment: This doesn't compile. Fix your typos and provide a [mcve].

Comment: This can’t be the actual code because it won’t compile. The if statement has a capital I and the function doesn’t always return a value.

Comment: Updated the question with actual code

Comment: That can't be your actual code unless it's in a language other than Java.

Comment: I believe the sample code is enough to understand the problem , we are talking about the logic and not about compiling the code. If anyone can suggest , Appreciate it

Comment: why `null != amount` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first if case `If (null != Amount || !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(Amount))` should be

```
if (null != Amount && null != Amount.getAmountToBePaid() && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(Amount))
```

as you use them later on, this ensures you won't get a **`null pointer exception`**, as long as `ObjectUtils.isEmpty(...)` handles `null` appropriately.

If the method returns a boolean based on those conditionals, I'd `return true;` if it manages through all of those if statements, `return false;` at the end to fulfill your `boolean` `return`.

Comment: Personally, I'd move All of those conditional checks on `ObjectUtils.isEmpty(...)` and `Amount` to a boolean method in `ObjectUtils`.

Something like `ObjectUtils.isAmountEmpty(Amount)` perhaps and return that.

Comment: I’d assume that `ObjectUtils` is a class name and `ObjectUtils.isEmpty` is a `static` method. And if `isEmpty` does not mean “is not `null`”, it’s hard to imagine, what it could mean, considering that it can accept instances of `Float`, `Amount`, `Money` and whatever `Money`’s `getUnit()` and `getValue()` methods return.

Comment: @Holger You're right, and I'd use a utility class for something that's used a lot on a global sense in my own code. You're comments on OP's question cover most if not all of the points in my answer as well. I figured I'd cover it in the null check anyways, as OP mentioned `null pointer exceptions`, without rewriting the entire code he provided.